# Disable certain styles while saving image in paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using paperclip to save images(version 3.5.1) and (rails version 3.2.21) . I have various styles defined in my model for paperclip

```
has_attached_file(:image, 
              :styles => { 
                            :logo => "300x2000>", 
                            :thumbnail => '100x100#',
                            :large => '1000x1000#',
                            :background => '2048x1024#'
                          })
```

For certain images I don't want certain style and for some images I want paperclip to process all the images. Example for profile type of images I want only `thumbnail` and `logo` style to be processed where as for gallery images I want it to process all the images (`logo`, `thumbnail`, `large`, `background`). Is it possible to achieve this in  paeprclip?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#dynamic-styles.

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :avatar,
     styles: lambda { |attachment| {
             thumb: (attachment.instance.boss? ? "300x300>" : "100x100>")
     }
   }
end`

Comment: I have this common paperclip modal reused everywhere in our app. So I don't want to change it.  I have seen in many places `before_post_process` function used in cases where we want to play with the processor images, but I don't understand how exactly to use this hook in my case.